# Ignore Alt+F4 in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I ignore <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> in WPF Application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can impement `OnClosing` event on `TForm` and set `cea.Cancel = true;` when cea is `CancelEventArgs` from `OnClosing` argument.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onclosing.aspx

### C#

```
private void Form1_Closing(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
   e.Cancel = true;
}
```

### C++

```
void Form1_Cancel( Object^ /*sender*/, CancelEventArgs^ e )
{
   e->Cancel = true;
}
```

### VB.NET

```
Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As _
   System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub 'Form1_Closing
```

Comment: Would this also prevent closing the app via the standard Windows White X at the top right?

Comment: If you want to limit the ways your end user can close an application, you'll specifically have to capture the event that is allowed to close the window, set some flag to say the app is now allowed to close, and then in Form_Closing, allow it to continue if your flag is set.

Comment: Anant Anand's answer should be the accepted answer as this will prevent it from closing other ways as well, not just by Alt+F4

Comment: Anant Anand's answer is better.

Comment: OP is asking about WPF, this is WinForms

Comment: This prevents the window from any kind of closing, so extra effort is necessary for handling "legal" closing attempts. I prefer the KeyDown answer.

Comment: KeyDown interferes with many controls basic behaviour. if you have custom key handling like universal key shortcuts across your app - you will never see the end of bugs where one fix invalidates one of your previous fixes.. you people simply dont know what you are talking about.. as usual on SO tho.

Answer (score 45):

Add this to the `UIElement/FramworkElement` from where you do not wish the Alt+F4 to work.

```
wnd.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(wnd_KeyDown);

void wnd_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.Key == Key.System && e.SystemKey == Key.F4)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the simplest solution that does not prevent it from closing other ways

Answer (score 12):

Simply use input binding like this in your View(Xaml) File:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Alt" Key="F4" Command="{Binding Path=ToDelegateCommandThatExecuteNothing}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```